# How to looping XWPFTableRow .copy without duplicate

Tags: java, foreach, apache-poi

I have an algorithm structure like this. How do I prevent my loop data from being duplicated? I'm using [apache-poi](/questions/tagged/apache-poi) 3.8.

```
XWPFTable TableArr1 = document.getTableArray(1);

XWPFTableRow getRow1 = TableArr1.getRow(0);
XWPFTableRow copiedRow = new XWPFTableRow((CTRow) getRow1.getCtRow().copy(), TableArr1);
int indexCounter;

for (AuditEngagementLHA l : ListDivAndDivHead) {
    copiedRow.getCell(2).setText(l.getDivisionName().trim());
    copiedRow.getCell(3).setText(l.getNameDisplay().trim());
    TableArr1.addRow(copiedRow);
}
```

The result: data row is duplicated.

[image]

My expectation:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `XWPFTableRow copiedRow = new XWPFTableRow((CTRow) getRow1.getCtRow().copy(), table);` your `copiedRow` will be a new row pointing to a copy of the underlying `CTRow` of the `getRow1`.

Then with `copiedRow.getCell(2).setText` you are changing XML content in that `CTRow`. After that, the underlying `CTRow` of the `copiedRow` is changed. Then using `.addRow(copiedRow)` you add that row to the table.

As you are doing this within a loop, you are always changing the former state of the underlying `CTRow` of the `copiedRow` by adding new content. This `CTRow` then has empty content from copied first row when loop gets started, first content after first looping, first content and second content after second looping and so on.

Seems as if the new rows always sall be copies from the empty first row of the table. So do always copying the `copiedRow` from the first row as first code line **within** the loop.

```
...
for (... : ...) {
 XWPFTableRow copiedRow = new XWPFTableRow((CTRow)getRow1.getCtRow().copy(), table);
 copiedRow.getCell(2).setText(...);
 copiedRow.getCell(3).setText(...);
 table.addRow(copiedRow);
}
...
```